# Flutter Firebase: (!snapShot.exists) is not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a Google Auth Sign in after the user signs in  a Method   `initalize();` runs and states wether the user is a new user or existed user. but its always detecting a user as new user and resetting the data to default.

Google Login :

> ```
> Future googleLogin() async {
>     try {
>       final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
>       if (googleUser == null) return;
>       _user = googleUser;
>
>       final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
>
>       final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
>         accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
>         idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
>       );
>       await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
>       initalize(); //<--------------The problem
>     } catch (e) {
>       print(e.toString());
>     }
>     notifyListeners();
>   }
> ```

Initialize() method:

```
initalize() async {
    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    final snapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('expenses')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get();
    if (!snapShot.exists) {
      print(snapShot);
      await SetTransaction(
          uid: user.uid,
          t_name: 't_name',
          t_amt: '0',
          isIncome: true,
          Category: 'Any');
    }
    else{print('Yesss siirrr');}
}
```

**Extra code**

The google login happens here:

```
return  Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset:false,
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xffedf1f4),
          body: StreamBuilder(
          stream:FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else if (snapshot.hasData){
            return LoggedInWidget();
          } 
          else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Something Went Wrong!'));
          }else {
            return SignUpWidget();
           }
          },
          ),
        );
```

Button inside `SignUpWidget();` class which helps to login:

```
  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {  //<------this happens on click of the button
                      print("Clicked");
                      final provider = Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(
                          context,
                          listen: false);
                      provider.googleLogin();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.google),
                          Text("Sign Up with Google")
                        ],
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 20, right: 20, top: 15, bottom: 15),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 70.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xffedf1f4),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                              offset: Offset(5, 5),
                              blurRadius: 5,
                              spreadRadius: 1),
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            offset: Offset(-5, -5),
                            blurRadius: 5,
                            spreadRadius: 1,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: `initalize` is future, trying  `await initalize();`

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh done still not solved

Answer (score 0):

`googleLogin` is a future method, it needs to `await`

```dart
 GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async{  
              ...
         await provider.googleLogin();
     },
```

More about [sync-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).

Comment: Changed stilll the same. Its resettting the data to default

Comment: did you also include `await initalize();`

Comment: Yess  I included ` await initalize();`, if you have time and you are comfortable I can give you discord id and i will show you the code

Comment: dont worry, hope others will help you to solve this

Comment: ok sir, but please reach out to me if you find any solution.

Comment: Can you try `if(!snapshot.hasData) return SignUpWidget();`

Comment: Still the data is getting resetted but , the positive thing is the data is not getting resetted immedtiately it is taking some time and then getting restted. (2 seconds type delay)